# como consultar una tabla de wordpres por fecha?

Tags: sql, wordpress, datatables

tengo una tabla creada el wordpres que contiene unas fechas y quisiera consultarlas

he probado dos formas diferentes y no me funciona

```
 $Carga = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE fecha_f >= CAST(".$fechaInicio." as datetime)");
```

y la otra forma que probé es esta

```
$Carga = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE fecha_f BETWEEN ".$fechaInicio." AND ".$fechaFin."");
```

ninguna de las dos me devuelve nada, pero si hago una simple si devuelve toda la información de la tabla

```
$Carga = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
```

he buscado a ver si wordpress tiene su propia forma de hacerlo y por eso no me deja pero no he podido encontrar nada . gracias por la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las comillas te están jugando una mala pasada. Supongamos que

```
$tabla = 'registros';
$fechaInicio='2020-11-24';
```

Tu sentencia

```
$Carga = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE fecha_f >= CAST(".$fechaInicio." as datetime)");
```

Resulta en un string `SELECT * FROM registros WHERE fecha_f >= CAST(2020-11-24 as datetime)`. Que es incorrecto.

El uso de la máscara YYYYMMDD es igualmente ISO-8601 válido y como es un simple número, puedes despreocuparte de las comillas:

```
$fechaInicio=20201124;
```

se concatenaría como `SELECT * FROM registros WHERE fecha_f >= CAST(20201124 as datetime)`.

Para el caso general, en donde tarde o temprano tendrás que usar strings y sus respectivas comillas, se usa [$wpdb->prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

```
  $Carga = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare( 
           "SELECT id FROM $tabla WHERE fecha_f >= CAST(%s as datetime)",
           $fechaInicio
       )
     );
```

En donde cumplo con decirle a MySQL que `$fechaInicio` es un string (`%s`), pero no intento escaparlo manualmente. La BBDD sabe mejor que yo cómo manejar sus caracteres especiales.